# Как показать значок при наведении на вертикальную линию в том месте, где происходит наведение в HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть вертикальная линия на веб-странице, и я хочу отображать иконку в месте наведения курсора на эту линию. Как можно добиться этого с использованием HTML/CSS?
Вот HTML и CSS код, который у меня есть для вертикальной линии:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.vertical-line {
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="vertical-line"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Я бы хотел отображать иконку в точном месте, где происходит наведение курсора на линию. Можете ли вы предложить решение с использованием HTML/CSS или подсказать реализацию на JavaScript, если это необходимо? Спасибо.

Comment: Что за иконка? И правильно ли я понимаю, что вы хотите, в том месте, где наводится мышь, что бы рядом с мышью было какое то изображение? При "гулянии" мыши по полосе что должно происходить? Что должно происходить, когда мышь покидает div?

Comment: У меня задача сделать resizable sidebar (как к примеру в Jira), но вместо дефолтной иконки мне нужно в месте наведения курсора на бордере сайдбара на ховер ставить svg иконку, когда мышь покидает div, иконка должна пропадать

Comment: иконка должна гулять не рядом с мышью, а появляться на бордере сайдбара в месте где был ховер

Answer (score 1):

```css
#x{       height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.vertical-line {
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href='https://learn.javascript.ru/mouse-events-basics' >
  <div class="vertical-line" id='x'
onmousemove='this.style="background: linear-gradient(180deg, gray 0%, transparent " + (event.clientY - 3) + "px , blue 3px, aqua 3px, transparent " + (event.clientY + 3) + "px, gray 100%);";'>развлекайтесь</div>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Внутри строчного тега не может находиться блочный..у вас в примере тег a внутри которого div

Comment: @MonkeyMutant, во первых если б не мог, оно бы не заработало(в сниппет то загляни хоть, зря что ли оборачивал?). во вторых, это не `block` а **`inline-block;`**. в третьих, у ссылки тут справочная роль. она не функционала ради используется, что как бы очевидно.

Comment: судя по количеству голосов вы не правы

Comment: @MonkeyMutant, та брось, задачка слишком пустяковая, что бы *за* ответ на нее голосовать. при этом пока ни одного минуса. но оно и понятно - ответ дан не мгновенно, из 44х вошедших в топик, хорошо если хотя бы половина видели этот "ответ") но как говориться, еще не вечер, кто-то да минусанет)))